# onsen ui carousel scroll issue on android

Tags: android, carousel, onsen-ui

I have the following carousel.

```
<ons-carousel swipeable overscrollable auto-scroll var="news_items_carousel" style="height: 90%; overflow:scroll; z-index:2 !IMPORTANT">
```

Each carousel item in it has a picture and some long text.

Everything works well on the browser but on an Android phone (Samsung S4) I cant scroll down to see the content in each `<ons-carousel-item>`. The carousel does actually move from one to the next when I swipe the screen so I guess its working, just not scrolling down to see the rest of the content. Hope am coming across clear.

Help needed urgently. Thanks

Comment: did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your content inside an `<ons-scroller>`. Basically something like this:

```
<ons-carousel>
    <ons-carousel-item>
        <ons-scroller>
         <img src="" /><p>{{longText}}</p>
        </ons-scroller>
    </ons-carousel-item>
</ons-carousel>
```